# XML posted values suddenly "lost" with text/xml content type

Tags: php, rest, symfony

I've been developing an "interface" were some client of mine, can call an API passing to it an XML structure and receive back another XML.

I've been create routes,methods and so on and try to use cURL for posting my data: everything works like a charm.

## BUT

.... if I add `Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8` to request's header, suddenly, in `POST` variable, there isn't anything anymore.

Any idea of what is going on here?

## Note

Obviously I don't add any piece of code, it's very simple and is composed by a route (standard symfony2 route), a method (dump POST) and the call that contain xml.
This is code of call

```
$ch = curl_init();    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'xxxxxxx:yyyyyy'); //where xxxxxx:yyyyy is setted but now censored
    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->url); // set url to post to
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8")); //without this all works
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $this->message);
```

where `$message` is something like this (just an example)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ROOT>
 <Message Option="1">Option 1</Message>
</ROOT>
```

---

After some days of debug, headache and so on, I found something that make my day, but that sounds weird to me.

If I log the incoming request, nothings seem to be posted to me (even if I post some xml).

**BUT** if i add `$logger->debug(__CLASS__.' '.$this->get("request")->getContent());` before log all incoming request, next request will be logged with all parameters that I'd post.
This sound like a kind of "lazy loading". So, by calling `$this->get("request")->getContent()` into my controller, I can get what I'm asking for (xml posted parameters)

Can someone help me understand?

Comment: if you are running through browser then view source code

Comment: @NanheKumar: what does it mean?

Comment: Can you post the full code of your controller?

Comment: @cheesemacfly: told you, is one line, and this line is a `var_dump` of the Request